# Expectation of $X^2$ where $X = x_1 + x_2 + x_ 3+ \dots +x_k$ with $P(x_i = 0) = 1-p$ and $P(x_i = x) = p$

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

We are told that $X = x_1 + x_2 + x_ 3+ \dots +x_k$ and that the $x$'s are independent. The probability of $x_i = x$ is $p$, while the probability that $x_i = 0$ is $1-p$. Use this to find $E(X^2)$.

The first thing I noticed was that if $P(X = x)$ that's just like saying what's the probability that only one of the $x_i$ is equal to $x$. So this makes me think it's binomial distribution. If that is the case $E(X)$ is just the sum of binomial distributions. However, I am not sure how you can handle $E(X^2)$ as $E(X^2) = E((x_1 + x_2 + x_ 3+ \dots +x_k)^2)$.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I guess $x_1,..., x_n$ are indipendent. The thing you are asking is then almost the same thing of calculating the variance of a binomial random variable.

Comment: @LucioTanzini Yes. I forgot to add that in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to perform the calculation directly.

First, we need to observe that for each $x_i$, we have $x_i^2 = x_i$, because if $x_i = 1$, then $x_i^2 = 1$; and if $x_i = 0$, then $x_i^2 = 0$.  Then

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[X^2]
&= \operatorname{E}\,\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i \right)^2\right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k x_i x_j \right] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2 + \sum_{i \ne j} x_i x_j \right] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \operatorname{E}[x_i^2] + \sum_{i \ne j} \operatorname{E}[x_i x_j] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^k \operatorname{E}[x_i] + \sum_{i \ne j} \operatorname{E}[x_i] \operatorname{E}[x_j] \\
&= kp + k(k-1)p^2 \\
&= kp(kp - p + 1).
\end{align}$$

The first step is to write $X$ as the sum of the $x_i$.  The second simply expands the square by writing it as a double sum.  The third step separates the terms for which $i = j$, of which there are $k$ such terms, versus $i \ne j$, of which there are $k(k-1)$ such terms.  The fourth step is simply the linearity of expectation.  The fifth step uses the fact $x_i^2 = x_i$ we explained earlier, and the pairwise independence of the $x_i$.  The rest is just algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding of what you've asked, using slightly different notation to make things a bit clearer. Let $X_1, ..., X_k \sim \text{iid}$ with $P(X_i = 0) = 1-p$ and $P(X_i = c) = p$ for some constant $c$. We are asked to calculate $E[(X_1 + ... + X_k)^2]$.

This problem becomes simpler if we define $Z_1, ..., Z_k \sim \text{iid Bernoulli}(p)$. Note that $X_i$ is equal in distribution to $cZ_i$. Thus, we have:
$$E[(X_1 + ... + X_k)^2] = E[(cZ_1 + ... + cZ_k)^2] = c^2 E[(Z_1 + ... + Z_k)^2].$$
Now, since the $Z_i$ are iid Bernoulli$(p)$, it follows that $Z_1 + ... + Z_k \sim \text{Binomial}(k, p)$. The variance of a Binomial$(k,p)$ is $kp(1-p)$ while the mean is $kp$. Thus:
$$E[(Z_1 + ... + Z_k)^2]= Var[(Z_1 + ... + Z_k)] + (E[Z_1 + ... + Z_k])^2 = kp(1-p) + (kp)^2$$
and it follows that
$$E[(X_1 + ... + X_k)^2] = c^2[kp(1-p) + (kp)^2]$$